# Is there a way to avoid overlaying subtitle text on video frame?

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I have a `20150928 WPA Basics.mp4` and a `20150928 WPA Basics.srt`. When play that mp4 file using VLC 3.0.4 on Windows. I see the following scene:

[image]

You see, the subtitle text overlays the video content, which is quite boring.

So, is there way to have subtitle text displayed off-screen? May be some special setting in VLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With VLC ([using this article](https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-change-subtitle-position-in-vlc/)) you can:

1. Add padding on the bottom -  Video > Filters > Croppadd
   [image]
2. Set forced subtitles position - Video > Subtitles / OSD
   [image]
3. Save for future use

Here is how the screen looks like:
[image]

P.S. Do not forget to enable the video filter

Comment: Great! It works, this is what ChatGPT 3.5 cannot answer today. ChatGPT just babbled some fake solutions.

Comment: But that answer needs some adjustments. I updated my answer here https://superuser.com/revisions/1784267/3 . with actual screenshots. You cannot see that answer in this webpage, because an offending user revoked my supplementing info into my own question.

Comment: @JimmChen, added the screenshots in my answer

Comment: Thank you, but don't you think it would be better if you add the very VLC UI playing a video file with subtitle text off the bottom? That would prove your setting really works.